# Conditional probability question 4 valves

Tags: conditional-probability

I need help with a question that has confused me.
**picture of the system :**
[A water flow system has 4 valves](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lyLN9.png)

For the water to flow A and D must be open and also at least one of the valves B and C.
The probability that a particular valve will be open is 0.8 and not dependent on the other valves.

1. **What is the probability that water will flow in the system?**
   my answer :
   The probability that at least one of the valves B and C will be open is :
   0.8*0.8+0.8*0.2+0.2*0.8 = 0.96
   the probability that water will flow in the system is :
   0.8*0.96*0.8 = 0.6144

2.**It is known that no water has flowed into the system, what is the probability that this was due to the fact that it was only a closed D valve?**

And here I was really unsuccessful, I found some answers but I have no way to check which one is correct, anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

Your answer to the first question is correct.  A simpler way to compute the probability that $B$ or $C$ is open is to compute the complementary probability; i.e., the probability that $B$ and $C$ are closed.  This occurs with probability $(0.2)^2 = 0.04$, hence the probability that at least one of $B$ or $C$ is open is $1 - 0.04 = 0.96$.

For the second part, it is easier to conceptualize the $B$ and $C$ valves as a single valve, say $E$, whose probability of being open is $0.96$ as you computed in the first part.  So now we have a series of valves, $A$, $E$, and then $D$.  Given that at least one of them is closed, thus no flow, what is the set of outcomes in which opening $D$, if it was not already open, would result in flow?  In other words, $A$ and $E$ must be open and $D$ is the only closed valve.  Otherwise, if either $A$ or $E$ were closed, opening $D$ if it was not already open, would not result in flow.  So, what is the conditional probability in this case?  Specifically, what is $$\frac{\Pr[(A \text{ open}) \cap (E \text{ open}) \cap (D \text{ closed})]}{\Pr[\text{no flow}]}?$$
Note that the probability in the denominator is the complement of the probability you got in the first part of your question.

Comment: So the answer is 0.8*0.96*0.2/0.386 = 0.397 .

Comment: That was one of my answers,just wanna make sure it is right. by the way thank you very much for the explanation it was very helpfull.